# How does caching works without max-age or expiry settings

Tags: caching, web, http-headers

I noticed a few websites such as Yahoo and Stackoverflow having response headers that neither contains a **max-age** in `Cache-Control` setting nor a valid date in `Expires` setting.

Example from Stackoverflow

```
Cache-Control: private
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 15328
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 03 May 2012 07:06:26 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

How does the browser keeps track of the freshness of the cached representation in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser simply doesn't cache the page. Every time when you visit the page, the browser requests the page to server. If it doesn't cache the page, the browser doesn't need to keep track of the freshness of the cached representation.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. It doesn't cache. Then why set cache-control: `private` instead of `no-cache`?